# jquery-scrollify – first section hash

Tags: jquery-scrollify

On my website i implemented scrollify with the following code, but when loaded, the first hash is set to #1 and not #home (as defined). Only when you scroll down and up, it's loaded. How could i change this?

```
$.scrollify({
    section : ".section",
    sectionName : "section-name",
    interstitialSection : "",
    standardScrollElements : "",
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    scrollSpeed: 1100,
    offset : 0,
    scrollbars: false,
    standardScrollElements: "",
    setHeights: false,
    overflowScroll: true,
    updateHash: true,
    touchScroll:false,
    });
```

Thank you for your support

Comment: So when you scroll down and then up, the hash gets set to #home?

Comment: yes exactly, can't figure out why it's not #home when loaded, but only when scrolled down and up again...